# How can I fix the method so that they process the list?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I have a model with a list, and I am trying to write a code to process the list, but nothing comes out. How can I fix or improve the method? I'm a beginner.

Code in model

```
public List<string> Poster { get; set; }
```

And my method

```
public async Task<ActionResult<int>> Post(News news){
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(news.Poster))
                {
                    var productPhoto = Convert.FromBase64String(news.Poster);
                    news.Poster = await _fileStorageService.SaveFile(productPhoto, "jpg", "news");
                }
...
```

Comment: You should use the right names for your variables, you have a list of Poster so it should be Posters ??! right ? So it's a list of strings but Convert.FromBase64String() take ONE string not a list of strings. You may need a loop to pass trough all the list and store each one.

Comment: Thx a lot! I fix it!

Comment: no problem :) good luck

Answer (score 1):

Your property `Poster` is a list, but in your method you use it like a single string. I think you need to iterate over the list:

```
foreach(var entry in news.Poster)
{
    if(!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(entry))
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: IsNullOrWhitespace()  shouldn't compile for a `List<>`

Comment: @HenkHolterman - entry is a string item from the Poster collection, so his use is correct.  Of course Poster would be better named as  Posters.